# javascript Подсветка выбранного Div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть `div` с классом `('.item')`, и в `div` есть `button` с классом `('.order')`. Таких `div` на странице несколько. Как по нажатию на `.order` подсветить выбранный `div`? (Поменять ему `background`).

Comment: С чем именно у вас проблема? Вы не знаете, как поменять бэкграунд? Или как выбрать именно тот div, в котором кнопка? Что вы уже пробовали сделать, и с чем конкретно у вас возникли трудности?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/vyo4jk8s/

Comment: Я разобрался с тем как поменять бекграунд по клику. Как вернуть его обратно при нажатии на другую кнопку?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/pkmyhuLz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery:

```
$('.order').click(function() {
    $('div.item').css('background-color', 'inherit'); # сбрасываем background для всех
    $(this).parents('div.item').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lfo2e98q/1/)

На css не получится, т.к. мы не можем менять свойства родителя и псевдокласса click не существует.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".order").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().css("background-color","green");
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Перед добавлением класса, уберите ешо с других

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.order').on('click', function () {       
  $('.item-active').removeClass('item-active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('item-active');
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nazarpunk/vyo4jk8s/2/

Answer (score 0):

Для оптимизации выше перечисленных примеров, я бы подправил в таком стиле:

```
var highlight = 'active'; 
var $selector = $('.item').click(function() {
    $selector.parent().removeClass(highlight);
    $(this).parent.addClass(highlight);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов на чистом javascript...

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
 e = e || window.event;
 var elem = e.target || e.srcElement;

 if (elem.parentNode.className === 'item') {
  let els = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
  els.forEach(function(e) {
   e.style.background = '#fff';
  });
  elem.parentNode.style.background = 'orange';
 }

}, true);
```

```css
.item {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
   <button class="order">Кнопка</button>
</div>
<div class="item">
   <button class="order">Кнопка</button>
</div>
<div class="item">
   <button class="order">Кнопка</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение с помощью `JS` и с помощью `input type="radio"`

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('#js button');

const handleClick = (e) => {
 const currentItem = e.target.closest('.item');
 const isActive = currentItem.classList.contains('active');
  
 buttons.forEach(button => button.closest('.item').classList.remove('active'));
  
  if (!isActive)
  currentItem.classList.add('active');
}

buttons.forEach(button => {
 button.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
});
```

```css
.container {
 margin: 20px;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

h2 {
 width: 100%;
 flex-shrink: 0;
}

button, .button {
 padding: 20px 40px;
 font-size: 14px;
 border: 1px solid #cecece;
 background-color: transparent;
 outline: none;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
 cursor: pointer;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item {
 margin: 5px;
}
.item.active {
 background-color: #cecece;
}

input[type="radio"] {
 display: none;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + .button {
 background-color: #cecece;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="js">
 <h2>JS</h2>
 <div class="item">
  <button class="order">Выбрать</button>
 </div>
 <div class="item active">
  <button class="order">Выбрать</button>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <button class="order">Выбрать</button>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <button class="order">Выбрать</button>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <button class="order">Выбрать</button>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
 <h2>С помощью <code>input radio</code></h2>
 <label class="item">
  <input type="radio" name="item">
  <span class="button">Выбрать</span>
 </label>
 <label class="item">
  <input type="radio" name="item">
  <span class="button">Выбрать</span>
 </label>
 <label class="item">
  <input type="radio" name="item">
  <span class="button">Выбрать</span>
 </label>
 <label class="item">
  <input type="radio" name="item">
  <span class="button">Выбрать</span>
 </label>
 <label class="item">
  <input type="radio" name="item">
  <span class="button">Выбрать</span>
 </label>
</div>
```